# Glass Bottle under water

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, glass

I am new here and in Blender... I have a problem with my work.
I made a Glass bottle with a message inside and placed it under water. I want to get something like a bottle in the ocean. The problem is, my bottle doesn't show when I'm doing a preview. I have a cube with principled volume. When I delete the cube, I have my bottle back. The issue is with the cube or with the bottle, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Keep in mind water has IOR of 1.33 and glass IOR is around 1.52. That is when the interface is between air and the material. So if light goes from water to glass, IOR will be 1.52/1.33=1.14... If the bottle has some liquid and air in it it will get even more fun.

Comment: I don't think your bottle is not showing under water. It is simply surrounded and penetrated by a homogenous featureless volume which is reflected on the surface of the glass - so it is not really showing anything because all it can reflect is the blueish uniform volume. How did you light the scene how dense is the volume? Is there anything shining on the bottle which should show up in the reflections? How does it look without the volumetrics?

Comment: @moonboots here are my files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17VOxLBEJ3YYlRgSWaGo7sTOdWa30bNY-?usp=sharing

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys So the IOR would be a reason? I' ve changed IOR of a cube and started see my bottle but all scenery was to bright

Comment: What does it give if you decrease the Density of the Principled Volume?

Comment: @moonboots I can see my bottle but all scenery is more bright. Doesn't look like a deep ocean

Comment: Yes but I guess this was your problem, now you need to correctly set your lightings and so on

Comment: @moonboots ohh! okay! So if change a value of Density and work with light should be fine? Now I have set up Density for 0.700 in my box

Comment: lower down the Density to 0.3 or whatever value that works, but if you want something that looks like a deep ocean it will depends on several things, not only the density, also the lights, noise texture, god rays and so on, there are some tricks for these effects

Comment: Wrong IOR will definitely be one of the reasons it looks incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here your main problem is that the *Density* of the *Principled Volume* is too high, lower it down, otherwise you won't be able to see the bottle.

For a deep ocean there are probably several things that you need to do, but first maybe try this setup: Plug a *Noise Texture* (set to *2D*) into a *ColorRamp* into the *Color* input of the *Principled Volume* (you could instead plug a b&w *ColorRamp* into the *Density*), tilt a bit the noise in the *Mapping* node:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I had a little bit fun with blender today and fixed my project. I followed your steps. Everything looks good right now. I have changed a little bit IOR too. Thank you all for a help. I appreciate that! I see great community here. Hope will be easier in the future.

Comment: Great then  ;)  .......